# Create a list in a loop

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to create a comma separated list inside a loop, but I think I am missing something. When I dump `item_id_list`, I just get items separated by a space - not a comma. Can anyone point what am I missing?

```
<cfloop array="data" index="doc">
    <cfif structKeyExists(doc, "id") >
        <cfset the_item_id = doc.id /> 
    </cfif>
  <cfset item_id_list = ''/>
  <cfset item_id_list = listappend(item_id_list,'#the_item_id#',',')/>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: *just get items separated by a space* That could not happen with the code above, because it overwrites the list each time. You need to post the actual code causing the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Create the list outside of the loop:

```
<cfset item_id_list = "" />
<cfloop array="#data#" index="doc">
   <cfif structKeyExists(doc, "id") >
       <cfset item_id_list = listappend(item_id_list, doc.id, ",") />
   </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
<cfset item_id_list = ArrayToList(data.id)>
```

EDIT: Oops. Can't reference a struct in an array like that. Instead try:

```
<cfscript>
    item_id_list = "" ;
    for (row in data) {
        if (structkeyexists(row,"id") ) {
            item_id_list = listappend(item_id_list,row.id) ;
        }
    }
</cfscript>
```

For loops like this, cfscript syntax is easier to see.